# Can I play a video backwards in AIR

Tags: apache-flex, video, air, adobe

I need to play a .mov file backwards in my Flex app. Some help??

Answer (score 2):

**Likely not possible.**

Video files are simply not designed to play backwards (the compression takes advantage of forwards [and backwards] temporal information) - a decoder would have to be specially-coded for such a feature.

Perhaps use an external tool to reverse the video.

*If* Flex allows per-frame control, then you may be able to achieve some results (perhaps not good ones) by frame-stepping backwards from the end. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to have the video on the timeline of a flash file (when you drag the video into flash it will give you the option).

then with actionscript you need to make sure the movieclip is paused and manually move the playhead of the currentframe backwards at about the frame rate of the movie.

it isn't trivial but it's possible.

Note that you won't have the sound working.

HTH.